# How to rewrite link_to with parameters to resource syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, link-to

Can this

`<%= link_to 'Item', {:controller => "items", :action => "update", :id => @item, :item => {:status => 'xxx'}}, :method => :put %>`

be rewritten with rails 3 resource syntax?

`link_to "Item", @item, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can use hamed helper:

```
link_to 'Item', item_path(@item, item: {status: 'xxx'}), :method => :put
```

You could also try button_to instead of non-GET link.